# Paypal sandbox no option to capture payment for received order

Tags: php, paypal

I've connected PHP website with Paypal API with their library.

I am setting intent to 'order' so no funds are captured.

However when i go to test merchant account there is no option to capture funds, only void and archive.

Why is that? Am i missing something? Is there something specific with sandbox account?

[image: Paypal dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please kindly note that if you want to capture the funds , firstly you need to
call DoAuthorization API for the order to authorize the Order, unless you can't capture the order directly.
Basic capturing the Order paymentaction scenario process is like as below.

Order(Calling API) -> Authorization(Calling API) -> Capture(Either API or PayPal page)

But if you use API only, just calling DoCapture API to capture the order(reference OrderID) directly.(this way , you needn't authorize the order.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be PayPal's feature (or defect?) that "Orders" could not be captured in merchant's PayPal account. You have to call DoCapture API to capture the funds.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/

The value for variable AUTHORIZATIONID could be a Order ID, or an Authorization ID generated from DoAuthorization API.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoAuthorization_API_Operation_NVP/